# JNDI and Spring configuration - jee:lookup

Tags: spring, tomcat, jndi

I wanted to use JNDI to publish my class as one of the resources. In context.xml of Tomcat I have

```
<Resource
   name="jdbc/dialect"
   type="pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialect"
   auth="Container"/>
```

in my web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>sqlite dialect</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dialect</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialect</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and in one of the Spring configuration files:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18706f6: defining beans
djfdoigjdoijfdsofjsdoij//the message added at the end of no-parameter constructor of SQLite dialect class
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean - Loading properties file from class path resource [config.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@18706f6: defining beans
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialect': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:146)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 22 more
```

I added printing to the end of no-parameter constructor, and it seems that the object is constructed, so I don't know why it complains about `Invocation of init method failed`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you need to use a driver not a dialect (this is my setup for MySQL, just change driver for your specific sql impl).

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myname" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
username="user" password="pass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://url/db"/>
```

and then

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>The JNDI Database resource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myname</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

I think you will want to set your hibernate.dialect to pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialect instead of what you are doing.

Comment: I know what you are trying to suggest, but I wanted to externalize hibernate dialect, I already have my data source configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/dialect"
    type="java.lang.String"
    value="pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialect"
    auth="Container"/>

<resource-ref>
    <description>sqlite dialect</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dialect</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

then perform your JNDI lookup, cast the value as a String and feed it to Class.forName() method.